# FlatList always growing to 100% height

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm building a screen which contains a `FlatList` at the top and some content at the bottom. The problem is that if my `FlatList` has a lot of items, the bottom content is going to be pushed outside the render area (outside of the View) and the `FlatList` will continue to expand until reaches the full height of the screen.

This is what I want:
[image]

Also, if the `FlatList` only contains 1 item, the height should be just the height of the item and not have scroll, since there will be enough space to show the item, and the scroll should appear only after the height is not enough to show all items (and of course, all the other content in the screen can't shrink or anything like that).

This is my component:

```
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Flex items="center" justify="center" style={styles.header}>
        <Text variant="subtitle2">{t("component.drawerMenu.title")}</Text>
        <Pressable
          style={styles.closeButton}
          onPress={() => navigation.closeDrawer()}
        >
          <Cross color={theme.palette.black.main} size={12} />
        </Pressable>
      </Flex>
      <Flex fill h="100%">
        <Box pv={24}>
          <FlatList
            data={[user]}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Flex
                inline
                items="center"
                justify="between"
                style={[styles.listItem, styles.listItemActive]}
              >
                <Avatar
                  url={item?.thumbUrl}
                  title={item?.firstName}
                  size={40}
                />
                <Box style={styles.primaryContainer}>
                  <Text color="white" variant="h5">
                    {t("component.drawerMenu.primaryAccount")}
                  </Text>
                </Box>
              </Flex>
            )}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box style={styles.divider} />
        <Flex fill>
          <Transitioning.View
            ref={ref}
            transition={
              <Transition.Together>
                <Transition.In type="fade" durationMs={200} />
                <Transition.Change />
                <Transition.Out type="fade" durationMs={200} />
              </Transition.Together>
            }
          >
            {menuItems.map((menuItem) => (
              <Stack key={menuItem.title} spacing={12} mt={24}>
                <Text variant="subtitle1">{menuItem.title}</Text>
                {menuItem.items.map((item) => (
                  <Box>
                    <Pressable
                      key={item.title}
                      onPress={
                        item.items ? () => onMenuPress(item.title) : undefined
                      }
                    >
                      <Flex
                        inline
                        items="center"
                        justify="between"
                        key={item.title}
                      >
                        <Text color={opened[item.title] ? "black" : "disabled"}>
                          {item.title}
                        </Text>
                        {item.items && !opened[item.title] && (
                          <ChevronRight
                            color={theme.palette.disabled.main}
                            size={18}
                          />
                        )}
                        {item.items && opened[item.title] && (
                          <ChevronDown
                            color={theme.palette.black.main}
                            size={18}
                          />
                        )}
                      </Flex>
                    </Pressable>
                    {opened[item.title] &&
                      item.items?.map((item) => (
                        <Box mt={12} pl={24}>
                          <Text color="black">{item.title}</Text>
                        </Box>
                      ))}
                  </Box>
                ))}
              </Stack>
            ))}
          </Transitioning.View>
        </Flex>
        <Box style={styles.divider} mt={24} />
        <Flex>
          <Pressable onPress={() => logout()}>
            <Stack inline spacing={12} mt={12} pb={12} items="center">
              <Text>{t("component.drawerMenu.logout")}</Text>
              <Logout color={theme.palette.black.main} size={15} />
            </Stack>
          </Pressable>
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

This is what my screen looks like with only 1 item in the array:

[image]

This is what my screen looks like with many items in the array:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that wrapping the `FlatList` inside a `View` was causing the issue. Also I had to add a style `flexGrow: 0` in order to not grow to fill the blank space.

Here is the fixed code:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Flex items="center" justify="center" style={styles.header}>
        <Text variant="subtitle2">{t("component.drawerMenu.title")}</Text>
        <Pressable
          style={styles.closeButton}
          onPress={() => navigation.closeDrawer()}
        >
          <Cross color={theme.palette.black.main} size={12} />
        </Pressable>
      </Flex>
      <FlatList
        data={users}
        style={{ marginTop: 24, flexGrow: 0 }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Flex
            inline
            items="center"
            justify="between"
            style={[styles.listItem, styles.listItemActive]}
          >
            <Avatar url={item?.thumbUrl} title={item?.firstName} size={40} />
            <Box style={styles.primaryContainer}>
              <Text color="white" variant="h5">
                {t("component.drawerMenu.primaryAccount")}
              </Text>
            </Box>
          </Flex>
        )}
      />
      <Box style={styles.divider} mt={24} />
      <Transitioning.View
        ref={ref}
        transition={
          <Transition.Together>
            <Transition.In type="fade" durationMs={200} />
            <Transition.Change />
            <Transition.Out type="fade" durationMs={200} />
          </Transition.Together>
        }
      >
        {menuItems.map((menuItem) => (
          <Stack key={menuItem.title} spacing={12} mt={24}>
            <Text variant="subtitle1">{menuItem.title}</Text>
            {menuItem.items.map((item) => (
              <Box>
                <Pressable
                  key={item.title}
                  onPress={
                    item.items ? () => onMenuPress(item.title) : undefined
                  }
                >
                  <Flex
                    inline
                    items="center"
                    justify="between"
                    key={item.title}
                  >
                    <Text color={opened[item.title] ? "black" : "disabled"}>
                      {item.title}
                    </Text>
                    {item.items && !opened[item.title] && (
                      <ChevronRight
                        color={theme.palette.disabled.main}
                        size={18}
                      />
                    )}
                    {item.items && opened[item.title] && (
                      <ChevronDown color={theme.palette.black.main} size={18} />
                    )}
                  </Flex>
                </Pressable>
                {opened[item.title] &&
                  item.items?.map((item) => (
                    <Box mt={12} pl={24}>
                      <Text color="black">{item.title}</Text>
                    </Box>
                  ))}
              </Box>
            ))}
          </Stack>
        ))}
      </Transitioning.View>
      <Box style={{ height: 60 }} />
      <Box style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, left: 24, width: "100%" }}>
        <Box style={styles.divider} mt={24} />
        <Flex>
          <Pressable onPress={() => logout()}>
            <Stack inline spacing={12} mt={12} pb={12} items="center">
              <Text>{t("component.drawerMenu.logout")}</Text>
              <Logout color={theme.palette.black.main} size={15} />
            </Stack>
          </Pressable>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: All I needed was the flexGrow prop. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the flatlist **maxHeight** style to the height you want, ex. :

```
<FlatList
    ref={flatlistRef}
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={(i) => i.id.toString()}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    style={{ maxHeight: 100 }}
/>
```

Comment: I can't do that, the other components can change their height, so setting a fixed max height will cause other bugs